# Inverse Kinematics on Baxter arm

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there guys,
I am working on a Baxter and ROS Groovy. I want to make the arm move from point A to point B while keeping the wrist joint fixed. I tried this with the IK Service but it messes up the wrist joint by moving it as well.
Any suggestions on how can I make the arm move from point A to B with a fixed wrist joint ?
Please help !!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173176/inverse-kinematics-on-baxter-arm/) by [ktiwari9](https://answers.ros.org/users/18753/ktiwari9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-06-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you request could be achieved using a cartesian path (if you can move between points in a straight line or can already generate some sort of cartesian waypoints) or using constraints while planning using MoveIt!. The latter (using constraints) was not completely implemented last time I read about it. For cartesian planning, [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/74776/cartesian-controller-for-ros/) is pretty comprehensive.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1